# How to tell when file is ready after deleting a view into it?

Tags: c++, windows, file, memory-mapped-files

I made a disk based hash table using windows memory mapped files, it makes 2 files - table file A and B. When the table file currently in use is full it resizes the other table file to be double the size of the old file, copies over all the data and sets the previous file's size to 1.

It works great up until 64 MB where it makes the alternate file 128 MB but fails to create a view in it and throws:
`error 33(ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.)`

I tried flushing the view every time i deleted one but doesn't help. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here is my view class:

```
template <typename T>
public class fileView {
private:
    int64_t idxStart = -1;
    int64_t idxStop = -1;

    int64_t mapSizeB;
    int64_t offsetB;
    int64_t maxMemB;
    HANDLE hMap;
    int granB;
public:
    int64_t posB;
    int64_t sizeB;
    T* data = nullptr;
    T& operator[](const int64_t& idx) {
        if (idxStart >= idx || idxStop <= idx) {
            if (data) {
                FlushViewOfFile((LPCVOID)data, 0);
                UnmapViewOfFile((LPCVOID)data);
            }
            posB = idx * sizeof(T) + offsetB;
            posB -= posB % granB;
            sizeB = min(mapSizeB - posB, max(maxMemB, granB));

            data = (T*)MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, posB >> 32, posB, sizeB);

            idxStart = (posB - offsetB) / sizeof(T);
            idxStop = idxStart + sizeB / sizeof(T);
        }
        return data[idx - idxStart];
    }
    fileView::fileView(HANDLE hMap, int64_t mapSizeB, int granB, int64_t offsetB, int64_t maxMemB) {
        this->mapSizeB = mapSizeB;
        this->maxMemB = maxMemB;
        this->offsetB = offsetB;
        this->hMap = hMap;
        this->granB = granB;
    }
    fileView::~fileView() {
        if (data) {
            //FlushViewOfFile((LPCVOID)data, 0);
            UnmapViewOfFile((LPCVOID)data);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Add a delay before creating the view just for a test (say 100-1000 ms). The system IO on such large files may be still processing even if your code has already advanced. The WinAPI IO behaves not synced, e.g. the system or 3rd party like antivirus software may still have a lock on this file. I had issues with small files being generated and deleted in a fast manner (unit test data) and I had lots of drop outs due to locked directories and files

Comment: I agree with Samuel on this, best way is to either use a timer or to use a system call to force the handles to be closed (which can be harmful to some processes)

Comment: The problem might go away if you use a new filename each time, e.g., by incrementing a number.  Alternatively, it would be more efficient to resize the existing file rather than copying the data to a new file.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to effectively resize without being very slow or putting the data in jeopardy(temporarily storing it in ram only) in a hash table. Creating a new file each time is an option, I'll probably try that if I cant make reusing work. Also I put the MapViewOfFile in a loop that would wait 100ms and repeat if GetLastError gave anything, so far its been going for 5 minutes and its still doing the loop :/

Comment: Might be worth a quick look in SysInternals Process Explorer (Find / File Handle or DLL) to see if some other process really is accessing the file.  You might get some extra insights if you post the lines of code trying to create the view....

Comment: I tried it, it reports around a dozen counts of my program and one count of "non-existent process". Are these all handles? Does that mean My views aren't actually closing? I checked the return value on UnmapViewOfFile and they are all nonzero

Comment: I tried not setting the file size to 1 in between uses and manually filling it with 0's(going through the whole file with views and using zeromemory) and now its functioning properly but its hella slow getting to the same size (around 100 times slower than with errors)